# Why can't this mysql user log in with password?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In phpmyadmin I created a user called "edward" with password and all privileges:

[image]

Yet when I try to log in via phpmyadmin, it says "Cannot log in to the MySQL Server".

When I try to log in on the command line (Windows 7), it won't allow me either:
[image]

But if I login in without a password, I get in:

[image]

and shows me only two of the tables.

I'm sure the password is correct and I've created multiple users which all can't log in with their passwords no matter how many rights I give them.

**How can I get this user to be able to log in only with password and see all databases?**

---

## Addendum:

Here is a screenshot from phpmyadmin showing that "edward" has just as many rights as "root":

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you set the password?  Try `SET PASSWORD FOR  'edward'@'%' = PASSWORD(  'YOU PASSWORD HERE' )`.

Comment: yes, I logged in as root and set the password again with that command, but I still can't log in as edward, as if there is some kind of global setting against anyone logging in except the root, I installed this with xampp

Comment: same thing is happenning to me, and the password was set correctly on the create user command

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you granted it access without password...
If a user has no password, logging in with one will always fail.

[Set the password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-password.html) for user, only then you'll be able to use `-p`

In addition, you might want to remove the `Any` user.

Comment: I granted it a password in phpmyadmin (as shown in the screen shot above), and a at the command prompt I logged in again and granted it a password with `set password for 'edward'@'%' = password('test');` but still can't log in with password, it's as if the password is not being set, but is showing as being set

Comment: your screenshot shows `%` host, however, you're accessing it from `localhost`, which makes a difference. You probably have other grant there, which matches *anyone* on localhost, without password. user with specified host is stronger definition

Comment: ok, I changed it from `%` to `localhost` and now it I can log in, and also, as you said, if I remove the "any user" entry, I can use `%` in edward, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Most possibly you have granted privileges on the server, but not on the databases. Try `GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'edward' IDENTIFIED BY 'password'`

Comment: I logged in as root and set the password with that command for the database "test" and "edward" but I still can't log in as edward with its password

Comment: So sorry: I messed up should have been `*.*`, not `*` - I edited my answer.

Comment: that still doesn't work, as is show in the screen above, the user edward has all rights, as much as root actually

Answer (score 0):

Same problem couldn't figure it out for nothing. Erased the database, removed the directory and reinstalled on Centos 6.3. The command line shows some data that is then scrolled quickly that solved the problem for me.  Pasted below.

PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !

To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:

```
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
/usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h cch-web-centos password 'new-password'
```

Alternatively you can run:

```
/usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
```

The last one is what worked for me. I entered a root password and it actually WORKED.  Entering a root password using mysqladmin without running that script gave me the same errors Edward reported.  Run the script, answer the questions, now using the root password works and logging in without the password is denied. This one drove me crazy as well.  I've installed mysql lots of times and this is the first time I've had this problem. Not sure if it is a yum/centos thing as on Ubuntu and Fedora I didn't have this problem.